# Weird CSS-padding property behavior with 1px and none. Can someone explain this?

Tags: html, css

[image]

(First question on SO, don't have enough reputation to directly post an image.)

Here's an image to show what's really going on, 1px of padding yields well over 20, while commenting out the padding property in total brings the border down to meet the content, instead of the content filling in the empty space above.

It's my first time making a full website and this is one of the little bugs I haven't been able to figure out.

```
div.main {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  /*padding: 1px;*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #DCD083;
}
```

versus

```
div.main {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #DCD083;
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Great question but we need some code to be able to answer you. This section might help you writing the code sample http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh, I screencapped my code and added it to the image above. I'll definitely add it to the post itself too. Thanks!

Comment: It's very hard to give any meaningful answers without the html. I think the best way for you to answer this question would be by providing the html and css as a runnable code snippet. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: What is your question? How do you want the box to behave?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `h1` tag for your text inside `div`.

This is not weirdness. Every `heading` tag like 'h1' will have `line-height` style property which is playing in your example with it's `height`.

Once check removing the `h1` tag by using `font-size` as shown in snippet

```css
div.first {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  /*padding: 1px;*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #DCD083;
}
div.next {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #DCD083;
}

div.with-font-size{
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <h1>
    TEAM ONE
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="next">
  <h1>
    TEAM ONE
  </h1>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="first with-font-size">
    TEAM ONE
</div>
<!-- see the difference of 1px here -->
<div class="next with-font-size">
    TEAM ONE
</div>
```